# Assign a Variable to Shell inline script of Azure release

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-task

I have an inline script where one of the command is the below one. How can i Replace LINUX_PASSWD with a variable in Azure release.

I have added LINUX_PASSWD and FILENAME as variable in Azure release pipeline but they are empty after release

`sed -i 's/password/$(LINUX_PASSWD)/g' FILENAME`

Comment: Can you change the example to a different ENV VAR than `*_PASSWD`?  If you do I'll upvote.

Comment: The task I'm working on now might make a better example: the fully qualified domain name and replacing that in kubernetes Ingress YAML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace your variables with their values, use $(varable_name) template. In your case:

`sed -i 's/password/$(LINUX_PASSWD)/g' $(FILENAME)`

Check the documentation: [Understand variable syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax), [Using custom variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#using-custom-variables)

> To use custom variables in your build and release tasks, simply enclose the variable name in parentheses and precede it with a $ character. For example, if you have a variable named adminUserName, you can insert the current value of that variable into a parameter of a task as $(adminUserName).